# Create an array based on two arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays `details` and `options` that coming from different sources (web api requests)

```
details: [
      { id: 'groups', option: true },
      { id: 'category', option: false }
]


 options: {
        groups: [ 
          { id: 'g1' },
          { id: 'g2' }
        ],
        category: [
          { id: 'c1' },
          { id: 'c2' }
        ],
        other: [
          { id: 'o1' },
          { id: 'o2' }
        ],
    }
```

I want to combine these tow arrays like

```
combined: [
        groups: 
            {
                options:[ 
                    { id: 'g1' },
                    { id: 'g2' }
                ], 
                details: { option: true}
            },
        category: 
                {
                 options:   [ 
                    { id: 'c1' },
                    { id: 'c2' }
                ], 
                details: { option: false}
            },
    ]
```

Basically if any `id` from `details` is matching to `options` property it should go in to new array under the same property name and all `details` except `id` goes to related `details` property.

What is the best way of doing that? Is lodash can handle that ?

Comment: Please add what you have tried, so that we can help you to solve the problem you are facing.

Comment: I'd say you have just **one** array.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado just updated the question, I am not building two arrays myself, they are coming form external api. So that is why I want to build one array based on these two.

Comment: options isn't an array, it's an object

Comment: Your question contains invalid code. And your expected `combined` array is not a valid array. You should take your time to ask and show your effort while asking a question, which is only fair since you're asking for help. Please read this - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want the items in both `options` and `details` ([intersection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_(set_theory))):

```
var details = [
      { id: 'groups', option: true },
      { id: 'category', option: false }
]

var options = {
        groups: [ 
          { id: 'g1' },
          { id: 'g2' }
        ],
        category: [
          { id: 'c1' },
          { id: 'c2' }
        ],
        other: [
          { id: 'o1' },
          { id: 'o2' }
        ]
    }

var combined = {};
details.forEach(({id: id, option: option}) => {
  if (options[id]) {
    combined[id] = combined[id] || {};
    combined[id].options = options[id];
    combined[id].details = {option: option};
  }
})

console.log(JSON.stringify(combined, null, "\t"))
/*
{
  "groups": {
    "options": [
      {
        "id": "g1"
      },
      {
        "id": "g2"
      }
    ],
    "details": {
      "option": true
    }
  },
  "category": {
    "options": [
      {
        "id": "c1"
      },
      {
        "id": "c2"
      }
    ],
    "details": {
      "option": false
    }
  }
}
*/
```

If you want to retain all items from `options` and `details` whether or not they match ([union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_(set_theory))):

```
var details = [
      { id: 'groups', option: true },
      { id: 'category', option: false }
]

var options = {
        groups: [ 
          { id: 'g1' },
          { id: 'g2' }
        ],
        category: [
          { id: 'c1' },
          { id: 'c2' }
        ],
        other: [
          { id: 'o1' },
          { id: 'o2' }
        ]
    }

var combined = {};

Object.keys(options).forEach(id => {
  combined[id] = {};
  combined[id].options = options[id];
})
details.forEach(({id: id, option: option}) => {
  combined[id] = combined[id] || {};
  combined[id].details = {option: option};
})

console.log(JSON.stringify(combined, null, "\t"))
/*
{
  "groups": {
    "options": [
      {
        "id": "g1"
      },
      {
        "id": "g2"
      }
    ],
    "details": {
      "option": true
    }
  },
  "category": {
    "options": [
      {
        "id": "c1"
      },
      {
        "id": "c2"
      }
    ],
    "details": {
      "option": false
    }
  },
  "other": {
    "options": [
      {
        "id": "o1"
      },
      {
        "id": "o2"
      }
    ]
  }
}
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [] notation to push details values.

```
options['groups']['details'] = true
options['groups']['category'] = false
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution for your problem

```js
var details= [
      { id: 'groups', option: true },
      { id: 'category', option: false }
];


var options= {
        groups: [ 
          { id: 'g1' },
          { id: 'g2' }
        ],
        category: [
          { id: 'c1' },
          { id: 'c2' }
        ],
        other: [
          { id: 'o1' },
          { id: 'o2' }
        ],
    };
 
var combined = {};

for (var i= 0;i<details.length;i++){
var obj = {}
obj.options=options[details[i].id];
obj.details = {};
obj.details.option=details[i].option;
combined[details[i].id] = obj;

}

console.log(combined)
```